# Find and print equals in a list

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, integer, find, equals

Given a list of 50 random integers in the range [n,k], where n is less than k. I would like to find
how many numbers are equal to each other and print them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `Tally` as follows.

First, let's generate a test list:

```
list = RandomInteger[{5, 10}, 50]

(* ==>  {10, 7, 5, 7, 10, 8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 8, 7, 5, 6, 9, 10, 6, 
         9, 6, 10, 8, 10, 8, 9, 7, 5, 9, 8, 5, 9, 7, 5, 7, 9, 10, 
         6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 6, 9, 10, 5, 6, 6, 6, 10, 9} 
*)
```

Then count them:

```
Tally[list]

(* ==> {{10, 8}, {7, 9}, {5, 7}, {8, 5}, {6, 13}, {9, 8}} *)
```